# Fastest way to access files stored in App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have around 300 sound files just copied to the main bundle in a group within Xcode.  Are they already indexed for speed or do I need to do anything to index them?  I'm wondering if I'm getting lag when opening and playing these files with simpleaudioengine (I'm using preloadeffect as well).  If I'm doing this incorrectly, what is the most efficient way to store and access files?

Comment: First things is to test if you are getting noticeable lag rather than wondering about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think indexing would help, but preloading them likely will.  Depending on how by the sounds are, maybe you can fit them all in memory.